# Getting window manager error "No interface method getCurrentWindowMetrics()"

Tags: android

I am attempting to get the usable(inset free) screen width and height for my window. Since past methods are deprecated by API 30 my hope is to use the technique discussed here in the section get bounds: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/WindowMetrics. To test this, I call `getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics()` in onCreate and assign it to a variable. When I run it I am getting a strange runtime error. Any help in fixing this is appreciated.

Crash: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getCurrentWindowMetrics()Landroid/view/WindowMetrics; in class Landroid/view/WindowManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.view.WindowManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)`

Code:

```
public class MainView extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;
private ProgressBar turnProgressView;
private GameLogicPresenter gameLogicPresenter;
private RelativeLayout boardLayout;
private BoardViewManager boardViewManager;
private ImageView playerGoingImageView;
private int numZoomsSoFar = 0; // Can be positive or negative.

private WindowManager theWindowManager;

private Map<String, Drawable> boardSymbolStringToDrawableMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_in_game_page);

    context = MainView.this;

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    final WindowMetrics metrics = getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();
```

Comment: What's the API level of device you're testing on?

Comment: It works on my device with android 11 and 10. but it crashed on my end-user devices

Comment: The same as me, it works on my device but not for the users, even after try and catch, it throws the error, did not find a solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you are trying to use is unavailable below API 30 (source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowMetrics).
Check out this code snippet I have written for you as it might solve your problems:

```
        var topInsets = 0
        var bottomInsets = 0
        var leftInsets = 0
        var rightInsets = 0

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(requireActivity().window.decorView) { _, windowInsets ->
                windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).let { insets -> //  check out WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars() as well as it might be a better fit for you
                    topInsets = insets.top
                    bottomInsets = insets.bottom
                    leftInsets = insets.left
                    rightInsets = insets.right
                }
                windowInsets
            }
        } else {
            requireActivity().windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars()).let { insets -> //  friendly reminder - WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars() 
                topInsets = insets.top
                bottomInsets = insets.bottom
                leftInsets = insets.left
                rightInsets = insets.right
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Windowmetrics cannot used in phone with api below 30,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31884067)